# Region bounded (Positive x-axis and y-axis)

Tags: calculus, integration

Curve A is defined as $\ln (x^2 + 4)$
Find the region bounded by curve A, positive X axis and Y axis.

My attempts,
I've drawn the function, split it into two parts and found out that it's the area between curve $\ln (x-2)$ , x axis and y axis.
How do I integrate, using what limits? Thanks!! The answer is $4 \ln ( 2 + \surd 3) - 2 \surd 3$.

Comment: The area bounded by the $xy$ axes and the curve is infinite. So something is wrong, or I don't understand the point.